# Python GCP-API permissions issue: compute.instances.list

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a 5 line Python script which is failing.

GCP indicates a problem with a GCP-API permissions issue.
I'm not sure though it is telling me the truth.

Here is the Python syntax:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
compute   = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
project_s = 'shining-sol-241621'
zone_s    = 'us-central1-a'

result = compute.instances().list(project=project_s, zone=zone_s).execute()
```

The above syntax depends on this env variable setting:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/secret.json
```

When I run the Python syntax I see:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import googleapiclient.discovery
>>> compute   = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
>>> project_s = 'shining-sol-241621'
>>> zone_s    = 'us-central1-a'
>>> result = compute.instances().list(project=project_s, zone=zone_s).execute()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/shining-sol-241621/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/shining-sol-241621'">
>>> >>>
```

Above, I see this msg in the error:

"Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/shining-sol-241621'"

At this URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=shining-sol-241621

When I look at the service-account permissions attached to my secret.json file I see that I have attached these permissions to the account:

- Compute Admin
- Compute Instance Admin (beta)
- Compute Instance Admin (v1)
- Compute Viewer
- Security Admin
- Owner

When I attached permissions to the service-account, I saw no permission available which looked like:
'compute.instances.list'

I did note that the Compute Admin permission has this description:

"Full control of all Compute Engine resources"

That description suggests to me that the permission should be able to do: 'compute.instances.list'

I am suspicious that GCP is telling me that I have a permissions problem but the problem is somewhere else.

Based on my description, what would be some good questions to ask in order to move past this bad API behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem after I assumed that the GCP server was caching bad info.

I created a service account with a name I had not used in the past.

I gave it just one permission: Project - Owner

I asked it to create a JSON-key.

I copied the key into $HOME/secret.json

I issued shell command:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/secret.json
```

I tried my 6 lines of Python:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import googleapiclient.discovery
>>> compute   = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
>>> project_s = 'shining-sol-241621'
>>> zone_s    = 'us-central1-a'
>>> result = compute.instances().list(project=project_s, zone=zone_s).execute()
>>> result['items'][0]['status']
'RUNNING'
>>> 
>>>
```

As you can see, it worked.
Yay!